# Where to find SQLite database in Ionic2/3 project?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ionic2, ionic3

I am new for ionic 2/3.

I have create SQLite database for my ionic2 project.

I have used following code for create data.db file for SQLite database

```
 this.sqlite.create({name: "data.db", location: "default"}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => { 
      this.database = db;
      this.createTables();
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("ERROR: ", error);
    });

async createTables() {
    try {
      await this.database.executeSql(this.userTable, {});
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error !", e);
    }
  }
```

code is working, database open.

I want to get `data.db` file which created by my ionic-SQLite project. SO, I can open it in SQLiteStudio for show database in GUI form.

Comment: default location for database in android is `/data/app.package.name/databases/db_file_name.db` i am not sure about ionic, but mostly will be the same

Comment: Have you managed to solve your issue? I want to get data.db with ionic, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with SQLiteStudio before, but I mostly use http://sqlitebrowser.org/ as a data viewer, but just to answer your question. I think the default database is stored in the private location and you will not be able to access it without the root permission.

Let's say you have created database with this method:

```
public getDB() {
  return this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'products.db',
    location: 'default'
  });
}
```

So here is what you can do:

```
adb exec-out run-as <your app package> cat databases/products.db > local_products.db
```

The above command will download the content from device to your local machine, and then you can use that file to view your data.

Comment: Can we change this DB path to some custom path?